# Trying to use regex to find a sub-string's urls in array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, ecmascript-6

I have an `array` of `strings`. I need to grab the `URL`'s value on each `string`. I have created a `function` with [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to accomplish this. It works fine, but there's an edge case I haven't been able to cover. When there is not any `URL:`'s value, I get the error: `Cannot read property '1' of null`.

This is my code:

```
const arrStr = [
  `describe
    url: https://url-goes-here-/1,
         https://url-goes-here-/2,
         https://url-goes-here-/3
  });`
  ,
  `
  before(() => {
    url: https://url-goes-here-/4
  });
  `,
  `
  before(() => {
    url: https://url-goes-here-/5
  });
  `,
  `describe
    // nothing http link here
  });
  `
]

const getXrayUrl = str => str.match(/url:([^;]+)/)[1].trim().split('(')[0]; // cannot read property '1' of null

const allXrayUrls = arrStr.map(item => getXrayUrl(item));
```

If I removed the `string` with no `URL` value from the `array`, I get this output:

```
[ 'https://url-goes-here-/1,\n         https://url-goes-here-/2,\n         https://url-goes-here-/3\n  })', 
  'https://url-goes-here-/4\n  })', 
  'https://url-goes-here-/5\n  })' ]
```

How do I cover this edge case & return another `array` with all the `string` in the level?

Comment: Because if *match* doesn't match, it returns *null*, not an empty array. Attempting to get the *1* property of *null* throws an error (because *null* isn't an object). So if *match* returns *null*, substitute an empty array, e.g. `(str.match(/url:([^;]+)/) || [])[1]` so if there's no match, the expression returns *undefined* rather than throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **match** function [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), it returns an `array` of matches, or `null` if no matches are found.

If you need to handle the case of a missing URL attribute so check match array is null before accessing the capture group as following:

```
const match = str.match(/url:\s*([^;]+)\n/)
// in case no match retrun empty string
// split the match on , to handle multi URL case
const url = match? match[1].split(",").map(item => item.trim()) : [""];
```

after that filter match results removing empty values as following:

```
arrStr.map(getXrayUrl).flat().filter(item => item !== "");
```

so final solution as following:

```
const arrStr = [
  `describe
    url: https://url-goes-here-/1,
         https://url-goes-here-/2,
         https://url-goes-here-/3
  });`
  ,
  `
  before(() => {
    url: https://url-goes-here-/4
  });
  `,
  `
  before(() => {
    url: https://url-goes-here-/5
  });
  `,
  `describe
    // nothing http link here
  });
  ` 
]

const getXrayUrl = str => {
    const match = str.match(/url:\s*([^;]+)\n/)
    // in case no match retrun empty string
    // split the match on , to handle multi URL case
    return match? match[1].split(",").map(item => item.trim()) : [""];
}

const allXrayUrls = arrStr.map(getXrayUrl).flat().filter(item => item !== "");

console.log(allXrayUrls)
```

console output:

```
["https://url-goes-here-/1", "https://url-goes-here-/2", "https://url-goes-here-/3", "https://url-goes-here-/4", "https://url-goes-here-/5"]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm bro! Do you know how to make the first three `URLs` returned as an array as well? 
```
[
   "https://url-goes-here-/1",
   "https://url-goes-here-/2",
   "https://url-goes-here-/3", 
   "https://url-goes-here-/4", 
   "https://url-goes-here-/5"
]

Comment: @ManuelAbascal check the updated solution Is it fit what you want?

Comment: Yes it is! However, the first item on the array contains three URLs instead of one, how can flatten it?

Comment: I already updated the solution to fix this issue try it